# Getting Id of HTML element added in for loop in Blazor Client app

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

New(ish) to Blazor and HTML.

I'm having difficulty obtaining the id of an img element that sits in a for loop in a razor page.

```
counter = counter + 1;
var imageName = "image_" + counter;
<img style="max-width:400px;max-height:400px"  id=@imageName/>
```

I have a button that passes the id of the image as a parameter to a function in the razor file which then invokes a JS in a razor.js file.

When I inspect the html in a browser (say I have 3 items in the for loop), I can see that the id of the img appears to be correct, e.g: "image_1", "image_2", "image_3".

The JS function that is called is supposed to get a reference to this image element using this code

```
 const image = document.getElementById(imageElementId);
```

The above line of code does not find the element.

imageElementId is passed as a parameter in the JS function.

```
window.setImageUsingStreaming = async (imageElementId, imageStream) => {
```

If I hardcode the image id, like this

```
 <img style="max-width:400px;max-height:400px"  id="image_1"/>
```

it works. This obviously falls over when there is more then one image in the for loop.

I suspect the answer to this is very straight forward, but I'm going to punch the monitor if I spend anymore time on it.

I know there is a better way of doing what I'm doing, but I want to crack this puzzle.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's F12 tools to inspect the elements *and* try different search paths? If you hit Ctrl+F in the Elements panel you can use CSS or XPath expressions to select elements, eg `#image_1`. In this page you can try `#custom-header` to find a div at the top of the page

Comment: So where's the button and the event handler for the button click?

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, that gave me the clue. I noticed that the image elements got renamed each time I clicked on a button. "counter" was declared in the code block and would constantly increment each time the page changed. I changed var imageName to be "var imageName = "image_" + i;" (i is the counter in the for/loop)

Answer (score 0):

"counter" was declared in the code block

@code {

```
private int counter = 0;
```

and would constantly increment each time the page changed. I changed var imageName to be

```
var imageName = "image_" + i;
```

(i is the counter in the for/loop)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).